# Autowire Spring Bean into interface for default method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to add a default method to an interface some classes implement, but my IDE complains (`bean may not have been initialized`).
Code would be something like this:

```
public interface IValidator {

    MyValidationBean beanToBeAutowired;
    ...
    default Boolean doSomeNewValidations(){
        return beanToBeAutowired.doSomeNewValidations();
    }
}
```

Is it just that autowiring into interfaces is not allowed or there's something wrong with the code?
Using `@Component` on the interface doesn't make any difference.

I'd rather keep this design instead of using an abstract class.

Comment: dependency injection in an interface won't work cause you can't instantiate an interface so you wont be able to inject anything.

Comment: Use the annotation in the implementation class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a Variable into interface is not possible in Java. It will be by default a `public static final` constant. So you have to do either the following:

```
MyValidationBean beanToBeAutowired = new MyValidationBeanImpl();
```

or the following:

```
MyValidationBean beanToBeAutowired();

default Boolean doSomeNewValidations(){
    return beanToBeAutowired().doSomeNewValidations();
}
```

And you can override the `beanToBeAutowired` method in the implementation class.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it will be cleaner to switch to an abstract class (in my case).

Answer (score 7):

i can think of solution as below -

```
public interface IValidator {

   public Service getBeanToBeAutowired();

   default Boolean doSomeNewValidations(){
    return getBeanToBeAutowired().doSomeNewValidations();
   }

}

public class ValidatorClass implements IValidator {

    @Autowire private Service service;

    @Override
    public Service getBeanToBeAutowired() {
        return service;
    }

}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing... I'd recommend providing a basic implementation to this answer to demonstrate how this might work

Comment: Same as with shazin's answer, would work but it's be easier in my case to switch to an abstract class. Thanks for the input

Comment: Maybe making it an abstract class will not do. Simply because the child class can only extend one parent class, and you may need to add this behavior to a class which is already extending something. Hence, you may need an interface. Example: PeriodicTask interface, Human parent class, Man child class. A Man extends Human and implements PeriodicTask, which means a Man is also a Human, and can execute all behaviors inside PeriodicTask. PeriodicTask cannot be another abstract class.

Answer (score 3):

***Just an idea***, send validation `bean` to interface as `parameter`;

```
public interface IValidator {

    default Boolean doSomeNewValidations(MyValidationBean beanToBeAutowired){
        return beanToBeAutowired.doSomeNewValidations();
    }
}
```

Your `callerClass`;

```
public class CallerClass implements IValidator{

    @Autowired
    MyValidationBean beanToBeAutowired;
    ...

    doSomeNewValidations(beanToBeAutowired);

}
```

Comment: I think this is not the case because the MyValidationBean is the same for all implementations. Hence, no need to be an argument.